# iOS - Auto resizing table view cells

Tags: ios, tableview, cell

I'm having some troubles with auto-resizing table view cells. I've been able to resize a cell's label based on its amount of text but I'm unable to adjust the cell height accordingly. Here's some code:

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

     _cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

     if (_cell == nil)
     {
         _cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     }

     PFObject *object = [_postsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     NSString *nameString = [object objectForKey:@"Name"];

     _cell.cellLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Posted by %@", nameString];
     _cell.cellPostLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"   %@", [object objectForKey:@"PostedDream"]];

     [_cell.cellPostLabel sizeToFit];

     [tableView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];

     NSLog(@"cell post label height: %f", _cell.cellPostLabel.frame.size.height);

     return _cell;
 }
```

Things to note are that I am using a custom table view cell called `TableViewCell *cell` subclassed from `UITableViewCell` and the cell and its labels were added through IB.
The label that's being adjusted is cellPostLabel and it adjusts perfectly depending on the amount of text, but it gets cut off due to the cell not adjusting as well.
I also tried calling `[self.tableView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];` and 
`self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;` in `viewDidAppear:` but still nothing. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Cells do not resize themselves except on iOS 8. Is this iOS 8? Do you understand how self-resizing cells work on iOS 8? You are not doing anything in that code that would cause self-resizing to happen.

Comment: And by the way, why are you calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`? That has been out of date since iOS 6. You should be using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`.

Comment: Hence the `[self.tableView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];` and `self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;` lines. Didn't work, but it was an attempt. I was using iOS 7 and running not the newest version of Xcode because I ran into a couple of bugs with the newer version a couple of months ago so I downgraded and never bothered to upgrade again. Also a bit of a newer programmer. And I did switch to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. Any idea how resizing is done on versions earlier than 8?

Answer (score 0):

Cell height is determined by heightForRowAtIndexPath method.

You can implement that method on your viewcontroller and return height you prefer.

If your cell should have different height you should implement that method and return different value each cells. Or not just return static value or set tableview's property rowHeight, in this case you don't need to implement that method.

Comment: I tried setting the table views rowHeight property but thats seems to set all row heights equal. I also tried implementing the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method but I ran into the same problem as I did with the rowHeight property, either all were changed or none were. Maybe I need to look into both a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: You can calculate every single cell height in heightForRowAtIndexPath. I think it's typical way to implement dynamic cell height prior autolayout.